# adding class starts with to dynamically created Radiobuttons on checked

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a couple of radio buttons and a couple of labels together like this

```
<div class="col-md-12"> 
     <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" id="slider_1">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" checked id="slider_2">
     <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">

   <!-- Slider Pagination -->
  <div class="slider-pagination">
     <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
     <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
     <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
  </div>

    <!-----slider Navigator----->
   <div class="navigator left">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="navigator right">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </div>


   <!-- Slider #1 -->
   <div class="slider slide-1 inner-container">

   </div>
   <!-- Slider #2 -->
   <div class="slider slide-2 inner-container">

   </div>
   <!-- Slider #2 -->
   <div class="slider slide-3 inner-container">

   </div> 
</div>
```

they are styled like this to have the label check the radio buttons on click:

```
  .slide-radio1:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page1,
  .slide-radio2:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page2,
  .slide-radio3:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page3,
  .slide-radio4:checked ~ .slider-pagination .page4 {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    border: 2px solid #ea2e49;
    background: transparent;
  }
```

as you must have noticed on every click of each label they check their equivalent radio button and style it, but now i am dynamically creating this elements and there are more labels and radio buttons,

```
var arrElement=[{"id": 1,
"imageLink": "https://images.gr-assets.com/authors/1193930952p8/61105.jpg",
"name": "TwichTV app",
"desc": "App that detects if station is online/offline",
"Info": "....."},
           {
             "..":"....."
           }]

     window.arrElement.forEach(function (val) {
        var keys = Object.keys(val);
        keys.forEach(function (key) {
          //here is where i append them to the DOM
          //for each item a radiobutton and label is created and added to DOM
        });
    });
```

how can i apply this style to all of them and not just 3. I came up with and idea to use class starts with

```
 [class*="slide-radio2"]:checked ~ .slider-pagination [class*="page"]{
   width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
   border: 2px solid #ea2e49;
   background: transparent;
 }
```

it worked but styles all the elements as checked and not the one equivalent to that label. How can i solve this problem. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: *"but now i am dynamically creating this elements and there are more labels and radio buttons"* - show us that code.

Comment: @MichaelCoker, thanks for your quick response, i have not created it, i just had the idea in my head and tested it, there i have added a concept of what it will look like, a JSON array that has many objects.

Comment: are you hiding the inputs and only displaying the labels? or are both the input and label visible?

Comment: @MichaelCoker both are displayed together like this

        <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" id="slider_1">
       <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" checked id="slider_2">
       <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
and a couple of labels

     <div class="slider-pagination">
      <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
      <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
     <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
</div>

Comment: are they together in your html? As in can you have the `input` and `label` beside one another in your html?

Comment: yes exactly, the comments dont properly show them, the below them is where the data resides, its a slider

Comment: I mean beside one another, like `<input><label><input><label>` where the label comes directly after the input it's a label for.

Comment: i made a correction of what it looks like on the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be to use Flexbox in combination with the adjacent sibling selector and a markup change.

The general trick here is to put each sliders `input`, `label` and `div` together in the markup, so the sibling selector comes into play.

With the Flexbox property `order` one then can re-position the elements and group the inputs, labels and div's in the same way your original layout looks like.

```css
.col-md-12 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-md-12 input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
.col-md-12 input:checked + label + div {
  color: red;
}

.col-md-12 input {
  flex-basis: 3%;
  margin-right: 27%;
  order: 1;
}
.col-md-12 label {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  order: 2;
}
.col-md-12 .navigator {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  order: 3;
}
.col-md-12 .slider {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" id="slider_1">
  <label for="slider_1" class="page1">label 1</label>
  <div class="slider slide-1 inner-container">
  container 1
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" checked id="slider_2">
  <label for="slider_2" class="page2">label 2</label>
  <div class="slider slide-2 inner-container">
  container 2
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
  <label for="slider_3" class="page3">label 3</label>
  <div class="slider slide-3 inner-container">
  container 3
  </div>  

  <!-----slider Navigator----->
  <div class="navigator left">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true">nav left</i>
  </div>
  <div class="navigator right">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">nav right</i>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow what a great answer, but the thing is i want the slider pagnination the way its, so i can move it around anywhere i want(top, or bottom of slide), let me try incorporating it. I will get back to you, if i dont get it right.

Comment: @AkinnifesiDamilola I made an update using flex direction row instead. Will most like give you a better way to line up the elements

Comment: @AkinnifesiDamilola Also note, by using the `order` property, you can move around any element before or after any other.

Comment: thats so awesome, its solved, i have this article on both flex box and grid that i havent been reading, with this  am def. going to read on 'em...what you just did seems like magic to me, i never thought it possible using order like that. thanks.

Comment: one more thing, during each click i translate the divs 100px in in either direction, intially, slide 2 shows first, that means checkbox 2 is checked, on clicking the other labels, its traslateX(-100px) or translateX(100px), how can i archieve ths where, i cant see anyway. The divs are absolutely placed and the slides are slide1(left: -100%) and slide2(left: 0) and slide3(left: 100%)

Comment: @AkinnifesiDamilola Well, that is a completely new question. Please accept mine, if you find it solve this first question, and then post a new one, where you add the just now commented code, and explain what you look for and we'll help you with that.

Comment: please look at the question i have added now at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089440/translating-an-absolutely-positioned-div.

Comment: @AkinnifesiDamilola I will be gone for today, but will look as soon as I'm back ... but before that you probably already have received an answer